# How to download a .stl file in angular with http.get?

Tags: angular, http, blob, observers, subscribe

I am trying to download a .stl file from a URL:- `https://cdn.thingiverse.com/assets/99/39/31/f9/33/90_Degree_-_4_Segments.stl`

I have created a service for the same - **app-stl.service.ts**, which accepts the URL and returns the required file --

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ImlStlAppService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


fetchData(filename:string) {

  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/STL');
  return this.http.get(filename, { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' });


}
}
```

Next in the app-stl.component.ts , I have the following code :-

```
  constructimage() {
  this.service.fetchData(this.filename)
  .subscribe((blob : any) => {
    let objectURL =URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    this.stlimage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    url = URL.createObjectURL(blob),
                img = new Image();
                img.src=url;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    else {
            downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
            downloadLink.onclick = document.body.removeChild(event.target);
            downloadLink.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        }
        downloadLink.click();

  });
```

I am not able to make it work. Could you please suggest any changes?

Comment: What's the error? Anything in the console?

Comment: I am not able to return the image.How to return the image to display on webpage?

Comment: You cannot display an stl file just like this I think, you need some kind of viewer.And you code is missing an`if` somewhere

Comment: I have given above 3 possiblities to download the .stl file. First, to subscribe to blob, second with the help of URL.createObjectURL and third with appendchild option. Which way to do this? I have the renderer ready for viewing stl files. Rendering is not a problem here ,only the downloading part.

Comment: What does the renderer expect to  display the image? a blob? An url ? The content of the `else` instruction is to download the file onto the user's browser, which is not what you want

Comment: The renderer expects a file with the extension .stl .

Comment: It'd be easier if you could create a stackblitz demo I think